# About flash builder mobile application iOS build file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, action

I have made one one mobile application in flash builder using flex mobile project
I have a question that "why size of an .ipa file is large as I export a mobile application as iOS application.???? in compare to that same application for android takes small size!!!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Because the AIR Runtime is embedded in the .ipa
The application for Android doesn't embed the runtime, the runtime AIR is an other application.